# Почему зацикливается программа на C

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Почему зацикливается программа? Программа, выполненная на C, компилируется с помощью gcc под Ubuntu. При запуске исполняемого файла происходит зацикливание и бесконечное выполнение программы.

Входные данные a=1,b=7,accuracy=0,001.

Метод, в котором программа зацикливается, представлен ниже.

```
void SimpsonMethod(double a,double b,double accuracy)
{
    printf("Simpson's method.\n");

    double I1=0;

    double m=4.0;

    double h=(b-a)/4.0;

    double I2=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        I2=0;

        int i=2;

        for(;;)
        {
            double x2=a+i*h;
            double x1=x2-h;
            double x0=x1-h;

            double y0=exp(x0)/x0;
            double y1=exp(x1)/x1;
            double y2=exp(x2)/x2;

            double S=y0+(4*y1)+y2;

            I2=I2+S;

            if(i<m)
                i=i+2;
            else
                break;
        }

        I2=I2*(h/3.0);

        if(abs(I1-I2)<accuracy)
            break;
        else
        {
            I1=I2;
            m=2*m;
            h=h/2;
        }
    }

    printf("I2=%f\n\n",I2);
}
```

Comment: Используйте отладчик.

Comment: Отладчик? Карандаш и бумагу!

Comment: @Igor пускай учится использовать отладчик. Задачи чуть посложнее все равно на бумаге не решаются.

Comment: Программа заработала, когда добавил #include <stdlib.h>. Тогда остается вопрос, как это влияет на программу.

Comment: @Flashnight Ошибка в том, что сравнивается целое `int` и число с плавающей точкой `double`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В приведенном коде неправильно используется библиотечная функция `abs`. Данная функция работает с переменными типа `int`. Т.е. эта функция имеет прототип

```
int abs(int);
```

Используя эту функцию невозможно достичь заявленной точности - возвращаемое ею значение будет меньше 0.001 когда `I1-I2` станет меньше единицы (при преобразовании числа с плавающей точкой в целое дробная часть будет отброшена).

В данной программе нужно использовать функцию `fabs`.

Теперь по поводу зависания.

Пока не было добавлено включение заголовочного файла `stdlib.h` компилятор должен был выдавать предупреждение о неявном объявлении функции (implicite declaration). На предупреждения компилятора лучше все-таки обращать внимание.

В данном случае происходило следующее.

Компилятор считал, что где-то определена функция, принимающая на вход значение типа `double` и генерировал соответствующий код. Компоновщик находил функцию с таким именем и связывал вызов с ней. Однако разные типы - даже имеющие один размер - могут передаваться по разному (соглашение о передаче параметров - внутреннее дело компилятора). В данном случае именно это и происходило, в результате чего в функцию `abs` попадало неверное значение, не равное 0, и, соответственно, возвращалось отличное от нуля значение и цикл не заканчивался.

После добавления заголовочного файла, содержащего прототип функции, компилятор выполнил преобразование передаваемого параметра к типу `int` и сгенерировал правильный вызов (хотя, по описанным в начале причинам, программа все равно работала не верно).

Поэтому на предупреждение компилятора о неявном объявлении функции нужно обращать пристальное внимание (многие задают опции компилятору, чтобы он считал это предупреждение ошибкой - несоответствие типов параметров функции ожидаемому может приводить к неожиданным последствиям). Ну и вообще использование прототипов в своем коде - тоже хорошая практика.